# NGINX - Spring Boot app ( "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found )

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, nginx

So I have spring boot app that i want to put behind nginx, problem is i get Connection refused when accessing localhost.

What my nginx config looks like :

```
    server {

    listen 80;
    server_name workaround;
    charset utf-8;
    access_log off;


    location / {
       proxy_pass http://172.19.0.3:8080/workaround;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;

     }
}
```

What I have running :

[image]

What I get as a response when accesing localhost

[image]

404 not found. How come Its looking for some etc/nginx/html/index, when this is in my docker compose file :
[image]

```
  nginx:
    container_name: workaround-nginx
    image: nginx:1.15.12-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    depends_on:
      - workaround
```

**What is wrong with my configuration?** How do i properly access my SB application?

- I have tried to use localhost instead of IP bud that didnt worked.
  Since it used nginx ip where app is not running.
- I was thinking about rewriting somehow default config of nginx bud how do i even do that from dockerfile , and then why would i have to be forced to do that when volume has mapping already set.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok i figured it out, and i even managed to fix it so it works with resources that have hash prefixes:

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

  server {
        listen 80;
        charset utf-8;
        access_log off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        location / { #this still has to be here, otherwise i get ISE
            proxy_pass http://workaround:8085/;
        }

        location ^~ { #this thing fixes hashes and resources
            proxy_pass              $scheme://workaround:8085/$request_uri;
            proxy_redirect  off;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
            expires 30d;
         }
    }


}
```